# Parsing with Jackson: throwing exception when format is unexpected

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am looking for ways to prevent Jackson from parsing data with "wrong" format. For example, if we wouldn't want to allow `null` as a text value, the following would just go ahead with it:

```
jsonNode.textValue() // this will always return a String
```

If we had to prevent `null` values from being parsed we would have to do something like:

```
if (jsonNode.isNull())
   throw Exception();
return jsonNode.textValue();
```

Similarly, if we try parsing an integer, it will try with almost anything.  Both [asInt()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#asInt()) and [intValue()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#intValue()) will return 0 if the parsing couldn't be done:

> If representation can not be converted to an int (including structured
>   types like Objects and Arrays), default value of 0 will be returned;
>   no exceptions are thrown.

Well, what if I want to treat these unknown, illegal, wrong, impossible or whatever-you-want-to-call-them conversions? There doesn't seem to be any conversion method that throws exceptions for you when this happens, it seems all of them perform the conversion no matter what.

For the last example, of course, I could have done something like in the first one:

```
if (!jsonNode.isInt())
    throw new Exception();
```

But having to do this every time a value is being parsed is an annoyance. I would expect some method to just throw an exception.

I am missing some obvious features from Jackson, or simply there are no methods like those I described?

Comment: Really good question. I wonder why the default approach in Jackson is trying to convert types at all costs, instead of expecting the right types in the first place and treating mismatches as logic errors.

Comment: Yeah... or at least they should have made methods to force-convert to the expected type, and then a different set of safe methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. At least not when `JsonNode`s are available. If Jackson encounters something it can not parse, `ObjectMapper` will throw a `JsonParseException` or `JsonMappingException`. `null` is a valid JSON data type, so encountering a null value is not unexpected. Checking for null is user's job - validation.

So you can:

- use your `isInt`/`isNull` approach
- implement your own [JsonParser](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-jsonparser.html)
- or look into [JsonSchema](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson#json-schema) (which is probably overkill)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to parse the `int` yourself:

```
int intValue = Integer.parseInt(jsonNode.textValue());
```

This will throw an `NumberFormatException` if the number is not valid.

Comment: Yes, I tried that one as well in some other method, but I was asking if Jackson had exception-throwing methods for these cases rather.